# PHP PDO query not inserting - Error HY093

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

After a lot of searching the web, the times I see this error, it looks really scenario specific. So far, I haven't found one that matched my scenario. I think my issue is coming from a prepared statement with spatial data type params.

The way I'm executing my code is:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO states(`name`, `poly`) VALUES(':name',GeomFromText('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(:coords)'));");
$res = $sql->execute(['name'=>$name, 'coords'=>$coords]);

if($res){
    echo "... Successfully Inserted<br><br>";
}
else{
    echo "... Failed<br><br>";
    print_r($sql->errorInfo());
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

The above is failing. The connection to the database has been tested. Since these are rather large geometry sets, instead of pasting my code, I'll show how I verified my SQL:

Dumping a raw SQL file and copy/pasting the SQL into a phpMyAdmin window, everything inserted just fine.

```
$sqlStr = "INSERT INTO states(`name`, `poly`) VALUES('$name',GeomFromText('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION($coords)'));";
$check = file_put_contents('./states/'.$name.'2.sql', $sqlStr);
```

So it's because of this, that I believe my sql is correct, but it my problem is likely due to the prepare/execute portion somehow. I'm not sure if spatial data types can't be assigned like this?

### Edit

I also want to note that I am on PHP version 5.5.9 and I've executed queries in the original method, with the params in the execute just fine.

Comment: Can you try `$sql->bind_param("ss", $name, $coords); $sql->execute();`

Comment: What is your php version? The square brackets shortcut is available only from php 5.4+

Comment: When you use bind parameters - you don't put the quotes in `':name'` should just be `:name`.  Not sure about how the second part works with quotes though.

Comment: Binding the params worked, but I'm still not sure why the original method didn't. I've edited the question to state that as well. I also noted that it's php v 5.5.9 and I've executed queries in this method before. I'm guessing it's the geometry object really throwing it off somehow.

Comment: @executable That's mysqli syntax, not PDO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way the code at the end could be working. Parameters in the query *must not* be put inside quotes.

Since `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(:coords)` has to be in a string, you need to use `CONCAT()` to create this string.

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("
    INSERT INTO states(`name`, `poly`) 
    VALUES(:name,GeomFromText(CONCAT('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(', :coords, ')')));");
```

Comment: That did the trick. My question is, why do I need to concat the geom portion? I believed the execute with params did essentially that behind the scenes?

Comment: `GeomFromText` requires its argument to be a string. You need to concatenate the fixed string `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` with the parameter to get a new string.

Comment: You believe wrong. PDO will never replace parameters that are inside quotes. It doesn't matter whether you use `bindParam` or put the parameters in the `execute()` argument.